# Proper way to call modal dialog from another component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modal-dialog, components

I have a component called department where I create a department using a modal dialog as shown below:

***department.component***

```
openModal(data) {
    //code omitted for simplicity
    this.modalService.showMOdal();
    this.create();
}

create() {
    //code omitted for simplicity
}
```

***employee.component***

```
createDepartment() {
    //???
}
```

On the other hand, I have another component called employee and I need to create a departmet by calling the open dialog and create methods in the department component.

What is the proper way to create department from employee component? Should I implement `openModal()` and `create()` methods in employee component as well? Or should I call the methods that are already defined in department component? I think it sould be better to use already existing methods and components in order to avoid from repetition.

Any example approach for this scenario?

Comment: Create a service to do this things and inject to your component.

Comment: I have a service in the example `modalService`. But what about the other stuffs? Should I create form fields of department again in employee component?

Comment: What about giving an example code?

Comment: I mean you can wrapper the modalService and create method to anonther service, something like that, then inject this service to both component.

Comment: Thanks, but I could not imagine it. Any example code pls with empty methods?

Comment: @KevinZhang What about your answer? Did you delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button type="button" (click)="addCampaignProduct()" mat-raised-button color="primary"
[title]="'ADD_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCT' | translate:lang">
<i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>{{ 'ADD_CAMPAIGN_PRODUCT' | translate:lang }}
</button>
```

---

### export class CampaignConfigurableProductsComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {  }

```
    addCampaignProduct() {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddConfigurableProductComponent, {
            disableClose: true,
            data: { campaignId: this.params.id }
        })
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
          this.ngOnInit()
        });
    }
```

```
export class AddConfigurableProductComponent implements OnInit { 


 addProduct() {
    const selectedOrderIds = this.addProductForm.value.colors
      .map((checked, i) => checked ? this.colorAttributeData[i].config_product_option_value : null)
      .filter(v => v !== null);

    if (this.addProductForm.value.actual_price == '') {
      this.sales_price = this.addProductObj.recommended_price;
    } else {
      this.sales_price = this.addProductForm.value.actual_price;
    }
    this.addProductObj['sales_price'] = this.sales_price;
    this.addProductObj['actual_price'] = this.finalPriceValue;
    this.addProductObj['campaign_id'] = this.data.campaignId;

this.campaignService.addProductCatalog(this.addProductObj).subscribe((response: any) => {
      if (response) { 

      }
  }, (error) => {
      this.notify.error('Something went wrong')
      console.log(error)
    })
}



}
```

Comment: I think `AddConfigurableProductComponent` is justa  form component and does not contain anything extra e.g. list,... ?

Comment: AddConfigurableProductComponent yes it's a component and it's use on store product data when fillup using dialog form. @Fredrick

Answer (score 2):

Extract this data logic from components and move it to a separate service.

```
// Move functions for opening the modal from DepartmentComponent to a service
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DepartmentService {
  constructor(private modalService: ModalService){}

  openModal(data) {...}

  create() {...}
}

// Inject the service into EmployeeComponent
export class EmployeeComponent {
  constructur(private departmentService: DepartmentService){}

  createDepartment() {
    this.departmentService.openModal()/create();  // whichever you actually need to call (should probably only be one that delegates to other functions)
  }
}
```

EDIT:
With some more information, a specific form (for creating a department) is meant to be displayed in more than one place in the app (in a modal and an employee component).

For this, create a component that holds the form (with create button etc) and the required event handlers (e.g. create department button) and display that where needed (the actual logic for creating the department should be in a separate service).

E.g. in the employee html

```
... employee information ...
<app-createdepartment></app-createdepartment>
```

And the modal should be something like this (component might have to be in EntryComponents, depending on angular version):

```
let dialogRef = dialog.open(CreateDepartmentComponent, {
  height: '400px',
  width: '600px',
});
```

(Docs for MatDialog: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)

Comment: Thanks for reply. In this approach I still have to pass the form fields to the service and as a result, I think I have to define form fields of department modal in emeployee component. If so, it is better to define the department form fields in employee and directly open it using the method that is used for opening employee form?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. The form field will be the result of the modal (modals can return data)? If so, I don't see a reason for needing to pass data from employee to department. You might want to return some information about the new department to the employee component for connecting the employee to that though.

Comment: Have a look at this (uses bootstrap which I don't know if you use that, but the general logic is the same) https://itnext.io/creating-forms-inside-modals-with-ng-bootstrap-221e4f1f5648 Potentially you want to map the form field value to an object (interface) and return that.

Comment: I need to give some additional information regarding to my situation. I build create department form in a modal in department component. I also need to create department when opening create employee form (I add this form and additional button for creating department). When clicking this add button, I want to create a department. At this step I am not sure what is the best option among following situations.

Comment: **1.** Building create-department-form again as I did in department component and define the necessary employee creation methods in the employee component?

Comment: **2.** Or, calling the department-create component and use its methods that are already defined in the department component? There is no data pass need, just think of using the same component again instead of re-creating. But even if so, I think I have to create department form fields in the employee component. Is that true?

Comment: Ok, so the actual question is about reusing a component. I added a bit to my answer. Essentially you want to create a normal component that holds the form and use that where needed (dialogs can be opened with a specific component that should be displayed).